# Out of memory exception occurring after repeatedly re-assigning a variable to a newly-allocated object

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, .net-2.0, out-of-memory

I have a program which loads files, these are often large, perhaps a few hundred MB. This is ok though as the computers running it are powerful.

Only one file can be loaded at any one time, and when a new one is loaded I re-assign the new file to the existing file object, e.g.:

```
myBigFile = new BigFile(fileName);
```

I had always assumed the previous file would be cleared from memory, but I am finding that after loading several files one after the other I often get an Out Of Memory Exception.

Is it necessary to call `GC.Collect()` before assigning a new file to my file variable? I had assumed that Windows would clear the previous memory once it was no longer being used?

EDIT

Further to some helpful comments, I went back and implemented IDisposable in the relevant classes and subclasses, using more or less the Microsoft template:

E.g, set arrays of classes to null, where each sub-type also has a Dispose() method:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myArrayOfClassType.Length; i++)
    {
       myArrayOfClassType[i].Dispose();
    }

    myChannels = null;                

    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

Then, when about to load a new file I did the following:

```
if (myBigFile != null)
{
    //dispose any previous instance:
    myBigFile.Dispose();
    myBigFile = null;
    GC.Collect();
}

myBigFile = new BigFile(fileName);
```

However then when loading the new file I would generally get an error, and arrays within the newly loaded file would turn out to be null, despite it just being loaded.

Is it possible that they are not being Disposed immediately and sometimes it is the new file which is present when the relevant clean-up occurs, and it is therefore being partly disposed straight away?

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your `BigFile` class dispose of unmanaged resources?  If so, you may want to enclose it with a `using` block to ensure the resources are released appropriately.

Comment: If your class has members that are disposable, it should probably implement IDisposable and you should be disposing it when you are done with it.

Comment: How are you reading the file?  It is possible you're not disposing of the resources after you've read the file.

Comment: Memory will *not* be released as soon as possible, but yeah, unless you screwed up disposing (or even then, in some cases) it should be reclaimed before you run out of memory.

Comment: You loading it into a string?

Comment: It loads into a custom class, which contains an array of another class (possibly thousands of elements long), which itself may contain integers, DateTimes, and up to 2000 floats. I've not implemented IDisposable, but should I have to do this with these data types?

Answer (score 0):

If the array that's being allocated when loading the file is big enough to get on the Large Object Heap, then you could be suffering an OutOfMemoryException from fragmentation. If you fragment the LOH to the point where you have 1.5GB free but the largest free space is 100MB, and you come along to allocate 101MB, then you'll get an OutOfMemoryException.

You could have a look at performance counters to watch the LOH size to give you an idea if this is the case.